# How replace '~' symbol in MVC with physical path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In Mvc application if the Layout is added with

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") .
```

Need a solution to replace the

> ~

symbol .So that Output should not be like 
    `/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css` in render page .

Instead

`localhost:xxxxx/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css` .

This Localhost need to be added when mvc application is run under IISExpress wherein It get modified to hosted application path when hosted into the server

Comment: Probably you may try using `Styles.RenderFormat` instead of `Styles.Render`: `@Styles.RenderFormat("<link href='" + @Request.Url.Host + "/{0}' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />", "~/Content/themes/base/css")`.

Comment: Tried with this Option but RenderFormat method does not  exist in system.web.optimization

Comment: Tried by updating the Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Comment: System.Web.Optimization should have `RenderFormat` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.styles.renderformat(v=vs.110).aspx. Try update the `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` package.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the path used in the `.Render()` calls is just an identifier or key that will produce the paths for the files that were added to it earlier.

This is what you'd normally find in `BundleConfig.cs`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
              "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

The `~/bundles/` part is **never** sent to the output when `.Render()` is called. What is sent are the **actual (*translated*) paths** from the `.Include()` call.

You should always make those paths start with `"~/"` so they will be output correctly. I have never found the need to include the server name, because the browser will by default request the file from the same server that delivered the web page.

Comment: Right, the relative path `~/` symbol is part of the bundling scheme and cannot be changed, I found it renders relative URL path without hostname part (i.e. localhost) on view side. IMHO, OP wants hostname part to be shown when the view renders in browser, like absolute path.

Comment: It may be better to investigate why the OP thinks he needs `server:port` in those paths. The answer is probably founded in misunderstanding of how relative paths work in browsers, or in where & how to use the `"~/"` prefix for paths in MVC.

Comment: I am rendering the View to the HTML String but the output HTML does not contains the Physical Location of the Scripts and Styles . So if we save that HTML string into HTML page. Then Jquery and Styles are not added to it